# Will this Flyback Circuit work ok?

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage

This is a follow on question to a previous post about enhancing inductive spikes as I couldn't add images to a comment.

So I have revised my approach somewhat in that instead of using back EMF pulses to feed to an electrolyser, I have put together a circuit to generate HV pulses using a suggestion from this forum of a flyback transformer, which seems a suitable device for the task.

To this end, I have drawn out a circuit idea in Keynote and attach it. I usually start this way before creating a 'proper' schematic as might be a forerunner to a PCB.

My question is will this work and are there any modifications or corrections to the circuit, such as for more appropriate components?

The other pic is the intended waveform across the power transistor and hence the primary of the flyback transformer. Again my load will be an electrolysis cell with distilled water as the dielectric.

Thank you

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have posted a transient graph from another web site and you have also copied and modified the circuit from that same site. You may have got them via this site but they are clearly originally from [this site](http://jnaudin.free.fr/html/lwhvps.htm) and you need to provide suitable references/credit back the that site. Also provide links to where on this site you found them (question to a previous post). You also need to provide a link to "suggestion from this forum" and note that "this forum" isn't a forum; it's a question and answer site (and not a talking shop).

Comment: Common convention is inputs at the left and outputs at the right, that is the case for the top half of the circuit but not for the bottom half which is confusing. The 2N3055 has an extremely low \$\beta\$ so I doubt that a 4.7 k potmeter is a good idea. When you turn the pot all the way up too much current might flow through it and damage it. I would simply use an LM317 based regulator and enjoy all the protections (short circuit, temperature) that it has. The 2N3055 should really be forgotten in new designs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.
This original design using a flyback transformer comes from: http://jnaudin.free.fr/lifters/labhvps/index.htm but I wouldn't need the square wave generator as I already have one that produces gated pulses. So it's actually the power transistor side that needs clarification.
The earlier post is at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/530500/how-can-i-increase-inductive-spike-voltage

Comment: Also, if I remove the 2N3055 then surely I won't be able to take off 0-60V which is required for the HV transformer. The LM317 approach may well give me a stable 12V but that's not all that is required.